# Rate of growth of a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wanted to know about this convention :

By rate of growth of R, we normally mean : (change in R) / (change in Time)

But Rate of growth of a geometric sequence "a(1+r)^n" is r, which is strange i feel

I am kind of confused, can anyone clear it

Answer (score 1):

Since the geometric series, or their partner the continuous exponential have varying rates of change, it is nice to find something consistant within them we can call a constant rate. The actual rate of change is the derivative $ df/dx $ which is discrete in the sense of a series. These rates of change constantly change. The rate in the series in not the rate of change, it is called the rate of growth because that is what $ a $ is getting constany multiplied.  This is NOT the rate of change. Two different concepts.  And since the derivative is kind of strange with a discrete series, the rate of growth tends to be used, but yhey are in no way the same thing. It gets confusing with the abuse of terminology.

Answer (score 0):

That is not strange at all. The geometric sequence in your question is given by $a_{n+1} = (1+r)a_n$ with $a_0 = a$. In every single "time step" going from $n$ to $n+1$ your $a_n$ becomes $(1+r)a_n$. So your growth rate per time step is $r$. You cannot break up this time step into smaller units of time since $n$ in the geometric progression has to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

> By rate of growth of R, we normally mean : (change in R) / (change in Time)

Actually no, the rate of growth of some quantity $R$ over the time interval $(t_1,t_2)$ is not $$\frac{R(t_2)-R(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$$ but  $$\frac{R(t_2)-R(t_1)}{R(t_1)}$$ and, when the time is continuous, the (instantaneous) rate of growth of $R$ at time $t$ is $$\frac1{R(t)}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dR(t)}{\mathrm dt}.$$ In discrete time, if $R(n)=a\,(1+r)^n$ for every $n$ then the rate of growth over the time interval $(n,n+1)$ is $r$ for every $n$. In continuous time, if $R(t)=a\,\mathrm e^{rt}$ for every $t$ then the rate of growth at time $t$ is $r$ for every $t$.